# Coq: Abbreviating Vernacular commands

Tags: coq, abbreviation

Is there a way to abbreviate (or define custom notations for) Vernacular commands like `Definition`, `Check`, `Notation`...?

Comment: Only by writing a ML plugin. However that is pretty easy to do.